# using charat with if and else in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this was asked before but I am unsure why this code is not working? Is if and else not possible using charat?

```
let str = new String ('Hello');
if (str.charAt(0) == 'H')
  //console.log('H')
  console.log(str.charAt(0))
else if  (str.charAt(1) == 'e')
  console.log(str.charAt(1))
```

Thank you,

Comment: It works fine, or if you originally wanted to do two conditions separately and output each, don't use else, use multiple if or switch case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working correct, because when you'll use `if` then it will check the condition inside the `if` block. When you'll use `else if` then it will only be checked if the above `if` condition didn't satisfies.

If you want to run code in 2 block independently then you should use `if` instead of `else if`.

Acc. to your code first `if` block will run and it will print **H** i.e, `console.log(str.charAt(0))`

```js
let str = new String('Hello');
if (str.charAt(0) == 'H')
  //console.log('H')
  console.log(str.charAt(0))
if (str.charAt(1) == 'e')
  console.log(str.charAt(1))
```

Comment: Thank you @Uttam .That helps me a lot and thank you for explaining that to me.

Comment: @MichaelHoyt please give it an upvote or mark as correct ans. So it could help others :)

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN,

> The if statement executes a statement if a specified condition is truthy. If the condition is falsy, another statement can be executed.

So once your `str.charAt(0) == 'H'` is true,JS will `console.log` H and move on. It will only execute the `else if` if the first `if` is false.

```js
let str = new String('Hello');
if (str.charAt(0) == 'b')
  console.log(str.charAt(0))
else if (str.charAt(1) == 'e')
  console.log(str.charAt(1))
```

You could see by changing the `str.charAt(0) == 'H'` to a wrong character, it will output `e` because the first `if` is wrong and JS will check the `else if` statement

Comment: Thank you @James .That helps me a lot and thank you for explaining that to me.